# Firefox upload field error: NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA

Tags: firefox, upload

I have an upload field that works in Chrome, but doesn't work i Firefox.

I've tried searching the web, but can't seem to find an answer.

Here's the error I get in Firefox:

```
NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA: Component returned failure code: 0x80460001     
(NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]
[Break On This Error]   

data.append(param, params[param]);
```

Comment: Make clear what your subject is. What "upload field" are you talking about? Is it related to programming? If not, this site is not the right place to ask, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you passing to `append()`?  Either you're passing a `String` object (in which case this will be fixed in Firefox 20) or you're passing something that's not a valid argument...